# Why is scanner skipping the last line?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a Java program which includes using scanner, but it seems it is skipping the last line of input.

I have already taken a look at similar posts that had problems like mine, but still, I don't find a proper solution.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    v1 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    String v2 = scanner.nextLine();
    v3 = scanner.nextInt();
    String v4="";
    scanner.nextLine();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

         v4 = v4 + " " +scanner.nextLine();

    }
    scanner.close();
```

So in my input values I have for v4:

```
1 2  
3 4  
11 12
```

but what it only saves to v4 is **v4=" 1 2 3 4"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>enter</kbd> after `11 12`, otherwise the scanner can not recognize it.

Comment: Unbelievable, I have spent 5hours on the problem and all I had to do was press enter

Comment: @RadoslavIvanov I would suggest to read the doc, it helps. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the last entry is not pointing to any property. So even you have a scanner and you can make a input there this values are not saving. If you want to save those values you should make another property under the scanner input and the property should hold those values.